# Interactive brokers getavailable margin Java

Tags: java, stocks, trading, broker, algorithmic-trading

I've been stuggling to figure out from Interactive Brokers' documentation how to query for account details such as available margin, available funds etc.

I tried to follow through their example and tbh got a bit lost; I can't identify exactly how to make a simple call to get the account detail.

Can anyone please provide a code snippet, Or some pointers as to the methods?

Much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `reqAccountUpdates(true)` method to begin receiving events concerning the account. Then all account data is fed via the `updateAccountValue()` callback. If you do not wish to subscribe to the account events periodically, call `reqAccountUpdates(false)` to end the subscription.